# Data tracking in DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I was trying to keep the history of data (at least one step back) of DocumentDB.

For example, if I have a property called Name in document with value "`Pieter`". Now I am changing that to "`Sam`", I have to maintain the history , it was "Pieter" previously.

As of now I am thinking of a pre-trigger. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make an audit log I'd suggest looking into Event Sourcing.Building your domain from events ensures a correct log. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589792.aspx and http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

Comment: The solution is pretty good, but I think its more complex when comes to the requirement I need. I just want to track the details in another collection or so. I there any way to do with an attribute? Like, if we add [Track] attribute to Name property, the changes will be logged. Anyway like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Cosmos DB (formerly DocumentDB) now offers change tracking via Change Feed. With Change Feed, you can listen for changes on a particular collection, ordered by modification within a partition.

Change feed is accessible via:

- Azure Functions
- DocumentDB (SQL) SDK
- Change Feed Processor Library

For example, here's a snippet from the Change Feed documentation, on reading from the Change Feed, for a given partition (full code example in the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)):

```
IDocumentQuery<Document> query = client.CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery(
        collectionUri,
        new ChangeFeedOptions
        {
            PartitionKeyRangeId = pkRange.Id,
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            RequestContinuation = continuation,
            MaxItemCount = -1,
            // Set reading time: only show change feed results modified since StartTime
            StartTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
        });
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<dynamic> readChangesResponse = query.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>().Result;

            foreach (dynamic changedDocument in readChangesResponse)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("document: {0}", changedDocument);
                }
            checkpoints[pkRange.Id] = readChangesResponse.ResponseContinuation;
        }
```